# SQL, missing end, but why?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an issue with my SQL procedure.
MySQLWorkbench advise me that it miss 'end' to my first SET, but not for the second. I don't know why.

```
DELIMITER $
drop procedure if exists pay10percent$
create procedure pay10percent(IN montant decimal(9,2),IN idResa INT(5))
begin
declare circuitid INT;
SET circuitid = (
            SELECT IDCIRCUIT  
            FROM RESERVATION 
            WHERE IDRESERVATION=idResa
            );
declare montantCircuit decimal(9,2);
SET montantCircuit = (SELECT PRIX FROM CIRCUIT WHERE IDCIRCUIT=circuitid);
end;
$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "miss 'end' to my first SET"? Could you tell us the exact error please?

Comment: The error is "Syntax error : missing 'end'".
If i execute, SQL code error : 1064

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must declare all the variables before using `SET`. Alternatively, you can drop `SET` and use that subquery as a default value:

```
declare circuitid INT DEFAULT (
    SELECT IDCIRCUIT  
    FROM RESERVATION 
    WHERE IDRESERVATION=idResa
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.
I didn't know that you have to declare all variables before.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's one thing to have an arbitrary restriction that `declare` must come at the very beginning of a stored procedure, it's another thing to not communicate this in the error message. :-(

Comment: Not necessarily the procedure, it can be any BEGIN .. END construct. Not an arbitrary restriction: it's requires by SQL standard and all SQL dialects.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is yet another example of MySQL design problems. Why should we be forced to declare all variables up front? Most modern programming languages allow variables to be created as needed. SQL Server and probably other database systems allow stored procedures or functions to declare variables when needed instead of requiring them before things like SET statements, etc. SQL Server doesn't use SET statements as much or it is not needed as much as some other languages like Oracle.